# Module Build Failed: Duplicate Declaration "Editor"

Tags: reactjs, webpack, semantic-ui, webpack-dev-server, draftjs

I am trying to implement "RichEditor" example provided by Facebook in my project Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react;
import { Component } from 'react';
import { Editor, EditorState, RichUtils } from 'draft-js';
import { Map } from 'immutable';

'use strict';

const { Editor, EditorState, RichUtils } = Draft;

//rest of the code...
```

Whenever I tried to build using `webpack-dev-server`, I am getting the following error. I checked StackOverflow to see if some other user has encountered an exact error. But, couldn't find one.

```
Module Build Failed: Duplicate Declaration "Editor"

'use strict';
> const { Editor, EditorState, RichUtils } = Draft;

export class ...{}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Note: I am new to ReactJS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're importing `Editor` up top, and then you are also defining it again when you are destructuring `Draft`.

You either need to alias `Editor` in the import of `draft-js` like this:

```
import { Editor as DEditor, EditorState, RichUtils } from 'draft-js';
```

From here you would use `Deditor` instead of `Editor`.   Then you would be free to name the const `Editor` below...

Or, just don't destructure the `Draft` object below.

Instead of `const { Editor, EditorState, RichUtils } = Draft;`, access the property of `Draft` with dot syntax. i.e. `Draft.Editor`, `Draft.EditorState`, etc...

Comment: second method helped. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad I could help! Looks like you're new here so I'll mention marking the best answer that works as accepted is standard practice. It makes it obvious to others you no longer need help on this, as well as feeds the point system.

Answer (score 0):

Also this duplicate declaration error happens if you are importing a predefined default import with the same name as a component somewhere else in your imports.

Example:

```
import bla from 'react-bla';
://more imports
://more imports
import bla from '../Components/bla/bla';
```